# Using Vite with multiple entry points, occasionally getting extra files in output folder

Tags: javascript, vite, rollupjs

I have 2 entry points to my app, with `vite-config.js` setup as follows:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    manifest: true,
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: '/src/app/app.js',
        pub: '/src/app/pub.js'
      }
    },
    commonjsOptions: { include: [] }
  },
  optimizeDeps: { disabled: false },
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

This results in 1 `manifest.json` file, and the corresponding `app.css/js`/`pub.css/js` in my dist folder, along with any other assets that my app references like images.

**Occasionally, running `vite build` will result in an extra set of CSS/JS files in my dist folder**. This extra file set is a random component or JS file from my codebase or node_modules, and oftentimes will contain a bunch of code that should be in `dist/app.js`. I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure this out. I've updated from Vite 3 to 4 and tried every adjustment I can find for the config file. Here's an example where `InputRadios.vue`, a component from my repo, is showing up and contains most of my app code.

```
[dist]
  [assets]
    - app.css
    - app.js
    - InputRadios.js
    - InputRadios.css
    - logo.svg
    - pub.js
    - pub.css
```

If I comment out any references to `InputRadios.vue`, then e.g. `VueRouter.css/js` appears in the dist folder. If I comment out `VueRouter`, some other random file imported somewhere in my codebase shows up.

Should this be working the way I'm expecting, or am I misunderstanding how `rollupOptions` works?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why I was getting the above behavior with multiple input entries for `rollupOptions`, but here's my solution: **use multiple vite configs**.

#### vite.config-dev.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  publicDir: false,
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    port: 3030,
    strictPort: true
  },
  preview: {
    port: 8080,
    strictPort: true
  }
})
```

#### vite.config-app.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    manifest: 'manifest-app.json',
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: '/src/app/app.js'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

#### vite.config-pub.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: false,
    manifest: 'manifest-pub.json',
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        pub: '/src/app/pub.js'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

#### package.json:

```json
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite -c vite.config-dev.js",
    "build": "vite build -c vite.config-app.js && vite build -c vite.config-pub.js",
    ...
```

This is running through an Express server that serves some private and some public pages, hence the 2 entry points. If anyone runs into this and needs full(er) code examples, post a comment.

Comment: hey, i had a same problem, and a same doubt too , did you find any satisfying answer or solution to this? apart from the one you mentioned above.

Comment: The above solution is what I've been running with for a while.